# crear una política de IAM de iniciar/parar servicios

Tags: aws, ec2, cloud, amazon, instancias

He creado la siguiente policita para que un usuario pueda  visualizar instancias de  aws y que pueda iniciar & parar las instancias que tengo. Debe ser que no esta correcto formulado ya que no se aplica correctamente.

```
{
    "Version": "2022-01-23",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Owner": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La versión no es la fecha en la que has escrito esa política, sino la versión que determina el formato del documento.

Actualmente solo existe una versión válida: `2012-10-17`, y es esa misma la versión que debes reflejar en tu política